# Firebase email verification "Subject" language

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for E-Mail verification.

Problem: I am only able to change the subject of the email, which is ok, but consider following situation:

1) Language of verfication email: english

2) I change the subject to: "Please confirm email address for XYZ."

Now, my app runs in germany and a german user wants to register and sign in.
Then he gets an Email which is automatically translated into german(just the email body),which is fine, but the subject still is in english! I am not able to edit the subject for each specific langauge! That is horrible. So the message body gets translated automatically, but the subject is just in one language. That is a horrible user experience.

I tried to change the language of the template to german and change the subject to german text and saved it. But then if a english user gets a verification email where the body is in english and the subject in german!?!?!

So how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714) (emphasis mine):

> For each email type, you can customize the email's sender name, sender address, reply-to address, subject line, **and—for password reset emails—the message**.

As such, you cannot customise the email verification message at all unfortunately. This is intentional:

[image: firebase email message help caption]

As far as I can tell, there is no way around only being able to set a single subject whilst the body is autotranslated. This is unfortunately reinforced by parts of [the discussion here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/WOa_MpxFETU/3nuYkFyJAwAJ).

The only solution I can see is using the default subject and message, which may then autotranslate both together.

Comment: Omg, so the simple "reset" of the template made the subject autotranslate again! Life saver! That is enough for me! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

In the Firebase console : Authentication => Template and at the bottom left of the square display it is indicated the choice of language. The templates will change the language on their own.